# quick basic math equation question

Tags: arithmetic

I've got a solution to a economy class calculation, but I can't figure out how they came to the answer. Could you help me?

-5p + 80 = 8p +-50

.......? = ......?

120 = 12p

p = 10

Extra: do you know which rule they are using to get from the first line to the 3d?

Many thx

Math beginner,
Frank

Comment: I am glad if you understood this, the same idea/technique with perhaps a bit more complexity is frequently used to solve several kinds of mathematical problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-5p+80=8p-50

80=5p+8p-50

80=13p-50

80+50=13p

130=13p (to get 120=12p at this step, you can multiply both sides by 12/13, but it's not necessary to arrive at the final answer)

p=10

Comment: thank you!
cause of confusion - 1 @%$ multiplication error

Answer (score 2):

Add $5p+50$ to both sides of the = sign, and then simplify each side.
(If you wish you can do this in two steps: Add $5p$ and then 50 to each side of the equality sign.)

**EDIT:** 
The above leads to the equation $130 = 13p$ which can be solved directly by dividing both sides of the equality sign by 13: $130/13 = 13p/13$, which after simplification gives us
$10=p$ -- which is the same as saying $p=10$.

Note: To reach the equation $120=12p$, that is contained in the original question, is not necessary in order to solve the equation.

Comment: still don't get it - after the start I just end up with:
120 = 13p
instead of 120 = 12p ..? what am I missing?

Comment: You are missing that 80+50=130, not 120.

Comment: many thanks - my bad for the multiplication error

Comment: @Ross Millikan: You are right, fixed it.